# sql create trigger with periodic execution not working as expected

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have a trigger that I would like to execute once in few seconds so I can batch database updates based on incoming events. However the expression in the when clause is not working as expected. I wanted db updates to be executed once in 5 seconds. Any help would be appreciated?

```
create trigger mytable_insert 
after insert on 'employee'
for each row 

    when (select (strftime('%s', 'now')-lastupdate) > 5 from mytime where id=1)
    begin
       ...
       db updates
       ...
       update mytime 
       set lastupdate = strftime('%s', 'now') 
       where id = 1;
   end
```

`mytime` table definition/initialization is as below:

```
create table mytime
( 
     id integer, 
     lastupdate TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
);

insert into mytime(id, lastupdate) 
values(1, strftime('%s', 'now'));
```

Comment: I have tried "when <expr>" in a different fashion, but still no luck!

...
when 5 < (select (strftime('%s', 'now')-lastupdate) from mytime where id=1)
...

Comment: Works for me. (Every 6 seconds because of the `>`.)